# Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated in relation with 2 examples

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd

That's a very frequently asked question but i'd like to pose it in relation with two examples that seem very similar in my eyes, and are yet the one correct and the other not.

Correct example:

```
k_th_element(X,[X|_],1).
k_th_element(X,[_|L],K):- K>1,K1 is (K-1),k_th_element(X,L,K1).
```

Wrong Example

```
length2(1,[_]).  
length2(X,[_|Ys]) :- X>1, X1 is (X-1), length(X1,Ys).
```

Why prolog complains or doesn't for each case?

**Update**: I think i got it. What i couldn't understand was that it doesn't matter what the predicate is but how you are calling it. so this is correct:
k_th_element(X,[1,2,3,4,5],3) because you have a value for K which is the right variable of "is" operator. But at the same time k_th_element(3,[1,2,3,4,5],Y) will not work, because Y is a variable, our "goal" and we can't have that in the right part of "is" operator. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: To make your relations more general and easier to understand, I recommend you use *CLP(FD) constraints* instead of primitive integer arithmetic. CLP(FD) constraints work in all directions, and your examples work if you simply use (instead of `is/2` and `>/2`) the finite domain constraints `(#=)/2` and `#>/2`. When using these constraints, any parts of both sides may contain variables, and you can use these predicates as true relations.

Comment: @Cris: Try to write it with CLP(FD) by answering your own question!

Comment: that's pretty cool @mat :) 
i'll update it like false suggested

Comment: Very nice! I agree with @false that you should post this as an *answer* and then accept your own answer, so that we can upvote it, and to benefit other readers. You can omit the parentheses: `X1 #= X0 - 1`. Please use `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` to access declarative integer arithmetic in SICStus, SWI and YAP. (In GNU Prolog and B-Prolog, it is already available from the start.)

Comment: You got it! Keep on going like this and you'll go far!

Answer (score 3):

as mat proposed, there is a more flexible way to achieve the same:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

length2(0,[]).  
length2(X,[_|Ys]) :- X#>0, X1#=X-1, length2(X1,Ys).
```

Comment: While this is declaratively all fine, you have still the option to make it more efficient (in an extra answer).

Comment: @false by omitting the first condition (`X#>0`)?

Comment: That would be non-terminating for `length2(0,Xs)`

Comment: then you may want to help me with that :-).

Answer (score 3):

First, there is the argument order. For `length/2` it is rather `length(List, Length)`.

For the case of a given list and an unknown length, your version is relatively inefficient because of all the `X1 #= X-1` constraints which implies about `N` constrained variables. The version `length3/2` has a single constrained variable. (It is about 7 times faster. I am still surprised that it is not faster than it is, maybe someone can help with another answer?)

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

length2([], 0).
length2([_E|Es], N0) :-
   N0 #> 0,
   N1 #= N0-1,
   length2(Es, N1).

length3(Es, N) :-
   length3(Es, 0, N).

length3([], N,N).
length3([_E|Es], N0,N) :-
   N1 is N0+1,
   N #>= N1,
   length3(Es, N1,N).

?- length(L,1000), time(length2(L,N)).
% 783,606 inferences, 0.336 CPU in 0.347 seconds (97% CPU, 2332281 Lips)
   L = [_A, _B, _C, _D, _E, _F, _G, _H, _I|...], N = 1000.
?- length(L,1000), time(length3(L,N)).
% 127,006 inferences, 0.047 CPU in 0.058 seconds (81% CPU, 2719603 Lips)
   L = [_A, _B, _C, _D, _E, _F, _G, _H, _I|...], N = 1000.
```

Comment: What is a pity is that `length3(L,0)` leaves a choice point open - entirely a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using [reflection predicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-reflection-predicates) one can build the following variant of `list_length/2`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_length(Es, N) :-
   (  fd_sup(N, Ub), integer(Ub)
   -> (  length(Es, M),
         (  M >= Ub
         -> !,
            M == Ub
         ;  true
         ),
         M = N
      )
   ;  length(Es, N)
   ).
```

The above implementation combines two nice properties:

- It works well with [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).

  In particular, `list_length(Xs,N)` terminates universally whenever `N` has a finite upper bound.

  Using SWI-Prolog 8.0.0:

  ```
  ?- N in 1..3, list_length(Xs, N).
     N = 1, Xs = [_A]
  ;  N = 2, Xs = [_A,_B]
  ;  N = 3, Xs = [_A,_B,_C].    % terminates universally
  ```
- It minimizes auxiliary computation (and thus runtime) by using the builtin predicate `length/2`.

  Let's compare the runtime of `list_length/2` with `length3/2`—presented in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31859644/4609915)!

  Using SWI-Prolog 8.0.0 with command-line option `-O`:

  ```
  ?- time(( N in 1..100000, list_length(_,N), false ; true )).
  % 2,700,130 inferences, 0.561 CPU in 0.561 seconds (100% CPU, 4812660 Lips)
  true.

  ?- time(( N in 1..100000, length3(_,N), false ; true )).
  % 14,700,041 inferences, 3.948 CPU in 3.949 seconds (100% CPU, 3723234 Lips)
  true.
  ```

---

Note that the above also works with SICStus Prolog: SWI's `fd_sup/2` is called `fd_max/2` in SICStus.

Comment: Your solution relies a lot on nice consistency. What if finiteness of `N` only shows after the first elements have been eliminated? I am too lazy for a counterexample

Comment: @false. Good point! Also, the potential gain with SWI (>5X) shrinks to something like "10% faster" with SICStus 4.5.0...